# addResourceType - how can I add Models_Mapper as a resource?

Tags: php, zend-framework, php-5.3, zend-autoloader

I'm writing a PHP application using
PHP 5.3 and Zend Framework 1.11.7.

I created model resource using the following command:

```
protected function _initLoader() 
{

     $loader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
        'namespace' => 'Default',
        'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH,
    ));

    $loader -> addResourceType ( 'model', 'models', 'Model'); 
}
```

now whenever i use a class name that starts with `Default_Model_` it goes and searches in models directory. under models directory i have a directory called mapper.

how can I configure that whenever a class is being used that starts with `Default_Model_Mapper_` to auto-load it from models/mapper ?

Answer (score 1):

ZF should find any directory under models automatically.  Also you shouldn't need to include the default module either.

```
Model_
Model_Mapper_
```

Also to setup ZF modules I have the following 2 lines of code in my application.ini file

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules[] =
```

And the following in my bootstrap

```
protected function _initModuleAutoload()
    {
        $modelLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
                'namespace' => '',
                'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/default'));
         return $modelLoader;
    }
```

I hope this is of some help

Kind regards

Garry

Answer (score 1):

Add this one:

`$loader->addResourceType('mapper', 'models/mapper', 'Model_Mapper_');`

The order in which you declare the two resource types might matter. So try it both ways; one of them should work.

Answer (score 1):

It is set by default in Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader in initDefaultResourceTypes:

```
$this->addResourceTypes(array(
            'dbtable' => array(
                'namespace' => 'Model_DbTable',
                'path'      => 'models/DbTable',
            ),
            'mappers' => array(
                'namespace' => 'Model_Mapper',
                'path'      => 'models/mappers',
            ),
            'form'    => array(
                'namespace' => 'Form',
                'path'      => 'forms',
            ),
....
```